# Django TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, smtp, smtplib

I tried sending email through smtp and email.mime with Django. I have decided not to use the django email because I want to automate sending of emails to several other emails from any user so the user will be required to put in his email and password to his gmail so smtp can send emails using his account to other emails

```sh
  Internal Server Error: /api/email/1/send/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/api/views.py", line 71, in post
    serializer.send(email_object_id=pk, validated_data=serializer.validated_data)
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/api/serializers.py", line 61, in send
    sender.send()
  File "/home/taycode/Desktop/emailsenderapi/api/utils.py", line 44, in send
    self.s.send_message(msg=self.msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 936, in send_message
    from_addr = email.utils.getaddresses([from_addr])[0][1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 112, in getaddresses
    all = COMMASPACE.join(fieldvalues)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

This is my sender class which I created

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from os.path import basename

class Sender:

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 587
        self.email = email
        self.s = smtplib.SMTP(host=host, port=port)
        self.s.starttls()
        self.s.login(email, password)
        self.msg = MIMEMultipart()

    def add_attachments(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as fil:
            part = MIMEApplication(
                fil.read(),
                Name=basename(path)
            )
        # After the file is closed
        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(path)
        self.msg.attach(part)

    def add_body(self, body):
        self.msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))
        return self.msg

    def add_recipient(self, email):
        self.msg['To'] = email
        return self.msg

    def add_subject(self, subject):
        self.msg['subject'] = subject
        return self.msg

    def send(self):
        print(dict(self.msg))
        print(self.s)
        self.s.send_message(msg=self.msg)
        del self.msg
        self.s.quit()
```

this is my serializer.py

```py
from sender.models import EmailObject
from .utils import Sender

class SendEmailSerializer(Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    @staticmethod
    def send(validated_data, **kwargs):
        email_object = EmailObject.objects.get(pk=kwargs['email_object_id'])
        for recipient in email_object.recipient.all():
            sender = Sender(validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])
            sender.add_recipient(str(recipient.email))
            sender.add_body(email_object.body)
            sender.add_subject(email_object.subject)
            for attachment in email_object.attachments.all():
                print(attachment.file.path)
                sender.add_attachments(attachment.file.path)
            sender.send()
```

This is my views.py

```py
class SendEmail(APIView):
    serializer_class = SendEmailSerializer

    @staticmethod
    def post(request, pk):
        serializer = SendEmailSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.validated_data)
            serializer.send(email_object_id=pk, validated_data=serializer.validated_data)
            data = {'status': 'success'}
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

It returns error everytime I call the SendEmail view in views.py.
how can I fix this??

Answer (score 0):

`smtplib.SMTP().send_messages` takes 3 parameters, from, to and message. In your code, you are only sending message to the moethod. You need to replace `self.s.send_message(msg=self.msg)` with:

```
self.s.send_message(self.email, self.msg['To'], self.msg.as_string())
```